# Shipping Restriction Extension Error Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions

I purchased an extension from a company called Magebright called, Shipping Restrictions. Before I purchased it, I specifically asked if it would allow me to restrict the USPS shipping option of Media Mail so that if anything that did not qualify for Media Mail was in the shopping cart, it would disappear as a shipping option. They said it would, so I bought it. Once installed I noticed a problem, I could restrict all of USPS but not any specific shipping methods. So I contacted them and they said they would fix it. They went in and expanded the options so that I could restrict only Media Mail. However, now the extension crashes. I can put as many media mail qualifying items into the cart as I want and it works fine, but as soon as I attempt to add an item that does not qualify it takes me to a 404 error page. If I disable the extension, it all works fine (without restricting the shipping option of course). They said they would fix, but a month has gone by with nothing done. 
  If I look at the error log, it gives me this:

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getCarrier() on a non-object in magento/app/code/local/Magebright/Shipingresriction/Model/Observer.php on line 44
```

If I open up the Observer.php file, lines 42-46 are as follows:

```
        if ($isEmptyResult){
        $error = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_error');
        $error->setCarrier($lastRate->getCarrier());
        $error->setCarrierTitle($lastRate->getMethodTitle());
        $error->setErrorMessage($lastError);
```

Any ideas, suggestions on how to fix this, or how to proceed? I downloaded an extension called Modules Conflict Detector to see if any modules were conflicting, but according to the extension, they are not. Any help on how to proceed would be appreciated. Thanks!!

Also - I have not been able to find any other extension offered or way to do this. And I need this function for my site.